# Obtaining data from an array to a dataframe

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe

so i have 2 datasets, the first one is a dataframe

```
df1 <- data.frame(user=c(1:10), h01=c(3,3,6,8,9,10,4,1,2,5), h12=c(5,5,3,4,1,2,8,8,9,10),a=numeric(10))
```

the first column represents the `user` id, and `h01` represents the id of a cell phone antenna from which the `user` is connected for a period of time (00:00 - 1:00AM) and `h12` represents the same but between 1:00AM and 2:00AM.

And then i have an array

```
array1 <- array(c(23,12,63,11,5,6,9,41,23,73,26,83,41,51,29,10,1,5,30,2), dim=c(10,2))
```

The rows represent the cell phone antenna id, the columns represent the periods of time and the values in `array1` represent how many people is connected to the antenna at that period of time. So `array1[1,1]` will print how many people is connected between 00:00 and 1:00 to antenna 1, `array1[2,2]` will print how many people is connected between 1:00 and 2:00 to antenna 2 and so on.

What i want to do is for each `user` in `df1` obtain from `array1` how many people in total is connected to the same antennas in the same period of time and place the value in column `a`.

For example, the first `user` is connected to antenna 3 between 00:00 and 1:00AM, and antenna 5 between 1:00AM and 2:00AM, so the value in `a` should be `array1[3,1]` plus `array1[5,2]`

I used a for loop to do this

```
aux1 <- df1[,2]
aux2 <- df1[,3]
for(i in 1:length(df1$user)){
  df1[i,4] <- sum(array1[aux1[i],1],array1[aux2[i],2])
}
```

which gives

```
   user h01 h02   a
1     1   3   5  92
2     2   3   5  92
3     3   6   3  47
4     4   8   4  92
5     5   9   1  49
6     6  10   2 156
7     7   4   8  16
8     8   1   8  28
9     9   2   9  42
10   10   5  10   7
```

This loop works and gives the correct values, the problem is the 2 datasets (`df1` and `array1`) are really big. `df1` has over 20.000 users and 24 periods of time, and `array1` has over 1300 antennas, not to mention that this data corresponds to users from one socioeconomic level, and i have 5 in total, so simplifying the code is mandatory.

I would love if someone could show me a different approach to this, specially if its withouth a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach:

```
df1$a <- array1[df1$h01,1] + array1[df1$h12,2]
```

Comment: Expanding this concept to a functional approach so you don't have to write out 24 statements - `vars <- c("h01","h12"); Reduce(\`+\`, Map(function(r,c) array1[r,c], df1[vars], seq_along(vars)))`